# Can't figure out a weird Path behavior in Rust

Tags: file-io, rust

I am writing a function that reads a `Path` and returns a `DirEntry` instance. There's some weird behaviour that I don't understand.

```
pub fn file_to_direntry<T: AsRef<Path>>(filepath: T) -> Result<DirEntry, Box<Error>> {
    match filepath.has_parent() {
        Some(parent) => {
            //..
        }
        // has no parent
        // this line would cause an error
        // Err(Error { repr: Os { code: 2, message: "No such file or directory" } })
        None => path_to_entry(Path::new("."), path),
    }
}


fn path_to_entry<A: AsRef<Path>, B: AsRef<Path>>(path: A, filename: B) -> Result<DirEntry, Box<Error>> {
    let filename: &Path = filename.as_ref();
    let path: &Path = path.as_ref();

    // this line prints, "" "."
    println!("{:?} {:?}", path, PathBuf::from("."));

    // when I replace this line to
    // for entry in try!(read_dir(PathBuf::from(".")))
    // it works perfectly fine

    for entry in try!(read_dir(path)) {
        println!("{:?}", try!(entry));
    }
    Err(From::from("no file found"))
}
```

[Full code on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fa07e627043890122ca31fba9b31a96c&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Right, but the error is thrown at line 31.

Comment: after removed line 32 & added comments, https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fa07e627043890122ca31fba9b31a96c&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: I included your new link in the question.

Comment: alright, thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code, you test with `PathBuf::from("todos.txt")`. This is a relative path, it does not include a starting `/` or `c:\`.

When you do `let parent = pf.parent();`, it will return `Some("")`. So the parent is an empty string, not `Some(".")`, and also not `None`. [`parent`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.parent) will only return `None` if the path terminates in a root or prefix. In your example above, you only included the `None` part, but that will not be called.

[`read_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html) will return an error if the provided path doesn't exist. That is the case when you pass an empty string like `read_dir(PathBuf::from(""))`, but it works perfectly fine if you use `read_dir(PathBuf::from("."))`.

Comment: Thank you! I just wonder why `PathBuf::from(".\todos.txt")`  works fine instead `PathBuf::from("todos.txt")` doesn't ? For me I think these two should be sematically same, do I missing or misunderstand anything?

Comment: I would agree that it makes sense to treat `.\todos.txt` and `todos.txt` identical. But reading the current documentation at [std::path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/), they are not. Normalization takes place, but adding a `"."` is not one of them. However, this might change in the future.

Comment: well, I guess I better stick with `.\xx` :)